# chrome, javascript, getCSSrule makes 100% cpu time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use some function to get specific css rule at runtime

```
function getCSSRule(ruleName) {
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
for (var i=0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    var rules = stylesheets[i].cssRules || stylesheets[i].rules;
    for (var j=0, rule; rule = rules[j++]; ) {
        if (rule.selectorText === '#title') {
            return rule;
        }
    }
}   
return false;
}
```

And using like this in ajax callback

```
var r = document.getElementsByClassName('#title')[0];
r.style.background = col;
```

It makes my cpu usage 100%. The problem is when I try to set the color, not the function itself (?) 
Any advice will be greatly appreciated. The problem is in Chrome, no problem in FF, even in IE6 works great.

Simplyfing, this is working in Chrom but with HIGH CPU usage and some other unexpected (other javascripts) behavior. Any clues?

```
var r = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[10]; // acess by hand

r.style.border = "auto"; // modify something
```

Comment: So why do you think the getCSSRule method has anything to do with the CPU usage?

Comment: When I use the code in Chrome, the CPU stays at 90...100% and I observed some other unexpected behavior. While debugging, it appears that modifying the accessed rule like above is the problem.

Comment: But the code works :) and this is annoying.

Comment: Looks like the second `for` loop is going into an infinite loop, doesn't it?

Comment: not at all, like I said it works and besides, simulation in FF is ok

Comment: It could depend on which element's(`r.selectorText`) style is being changed, how many such elements are present in the HTML and how they interact. Could you share a url or try to reproduce it on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCSSRule(ruleName) {
    var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i=0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
        var rules = stylesheets[i].cssRules || stylesheets[i].rules;
        for (var j=0, k=rules.length, rule; j < k; rule = rules[j++]; ) {
            if (rule.selectorText === '#title') {
                return rule;
            }
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

A conditional statement is missing in the second `for` loop. You need to check for `rules.length`.

Comment: ok, I agree and I will check right away. But please check my first post, the same situation when NOT using the function at all!

Comment: As far as the rules array is compact and a not existing cssRule is falsy, his loop statement was right. This loop style is a first step in loop optimization, on the way to while loops.

Answer (score 0):

After pulling out my hair I found another solution, very simple and cross browser. In case anyone needs :)

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
<a href="config.htm">Configuration</a>
<a href="status.htm">Status</a>
...
</div>
```

Now in css, there are 2 "menu" classes, one for ON and one for OFF (just to detect Online and Offline).
And changing from javacript (at 10mS rate ajax callback) works perfect

```
if(Offline)
{   
  var elem = document.getElementById('menu');
elem.className = 'menudis';
}
```